# How to persist an html radio button selection from a Backbone to the server

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

In a Backbone view I have various elements for a user to select, such as dropdown menus and checkboxes. I'm passing these user model preferences to the server, so when the user logs back in, they are stored. They work fine, however my radio button selection isn't being stored for some reason, even though I'm doing it in the same way as the other elements. If I check a selection, it reverts back to default on refresh.

From what I can tell by trying to debug it in console, it seems as though the radio button attribute is being saved, so I'm unsure why it isn't working. Hope I've explained this clearly enough. If anyone could help me solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <label class="radio">
        <input id="all_selection" type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="all" <%=(options.location_mode=="all" ? "checked=='true'":"")%>>
        All Locations
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input id="some_selections" type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="selected" <%=(options.location_mode=="selected" ? "checked=='true'":"")%>>
        Selected Locations
    </label>
```

Backbone code (note: I've included the parts of the code which I believe to relevant):

```
    var BbView = Backbone.View.extend({

         events: {
            'change input[name="location"]:radio': "locationSelect"
         },

         locationSelect: function(e) {
         if ($("#some_selections").is(":checked")) {
            $('#id_locations').prop('disabled', false);
         }
         else {
            $('#id_locations').prop('disabled', 'disabled');  
         }
         this.updateModel();
     },

         updateModel: function(e) {
         this.createModel();
         },

         createModel: function() {
              var optionsForSave = {
                  type:this.options.type
              };

              var locationMode = this.$el.find("input[name='location']:checked").val();
              var locations = this.$el.find("#id_locations").val();

              if(locationMode) {
                optionsForSave['location_mode'] = locationMode;
              }
              if(locations) {
                optionsForSave['id_locations'] = locations;
              }

              this.model.set({
            options: optionsForSave,
        });
        if(this.options.type) {
            this.options.componentsCollection.add(this.model);
            Backbone.sync("create",this.model);
            this.model.save({}, {

                }
            });
        }
        });
```

Comment: In your Underscore template, you're outputting `checked=="true"` if your variable is set. If you make that `checked="true"`, does that change anything?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alex, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference. I think it might be something to do with the way the data is being is being saved, because I see the correct attributes for each radio selection in Console prior to saving. It's probably something super simple I'm missing!

Comment: with the radio input i thought you had to use checked="checked"

Comment: Hi Quince, I'm unsure if that's the case. I did try it though and it hasn't solved my problem unfortunately.